# Angular global error handing - specify module that error occurred in

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, rxjs, custom-error-handling

I've got an Angular application that's built to house multiple child applications. In this app, I've implemented a `GlobalErrorHandlerService` which overrides Angular's default `ErrorHandler`:

**global-error-handler.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, ErrorHandler, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import {ErrorLogger} from '../services/error-logger.service';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

// Global error handler for logging errors
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandlerService extends ErrorHandler {
    constructor(private injector : Injector, private errorLoggerService: ErrorLoggerService) {


        super();
    }

    handleError(error: any) {
      let loggerService = this.injector.get(ErrorLoggerService);
      loggerService.logError(error)    
      .subscribe(
        data => console.warn(data),
        error => {throw error},
        () => console.log("empty")
      );

  }
}
```

This automatically catches all errors and sends them to a global `ErrorLoggerService` for logging these errors to a database:

**error-logger.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpRequest, HttpHeaders, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpParams, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter, catchError, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AppConstants } from '../app-constants/app-constants';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ErrorLoggerService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { };

  logError(error: any):Observable<any> {

    const date = new Date().toUTCString();

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }),
      withCredentials: true
    };

    //******** log errors based on type ********//
    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {

      //** POST error to db **//
      return this.http.post('http://path-to-my-api-model-which-logs-to-db',
      { Date: date, type: error.type, message: error.message, stackTrace: "testStackTraceSERVICE", lineNumber: "testLineNumber", code: "testCode" },
      httpOptions)

    }
    else if (error instanceof TypeError) {

      //** POST error to db **//
      return this.http.post('http://path-to-my-api-model-which-logs-to-db',
      { Date: date, type: error.name, message: error.message, stackTrace: error.stack, lineNumber: "TypeError lineNumber", code: "testCode" },
      httpOptions)
    }
    else if (error instanceof Error) {
      console.error(date, AppConstants.generalError, error.message, error.stack);
    }
    else if(error instanceof ErrorEvent){
      //A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error(date, AppConstants.generalError, error.message, error.filename);
    }
    else {
      console.error(date, AppConstants.somethingHappened, error.message, error.stack);
    }
  }
}
```

This logs properly to the db. But in this database table which logs our errors, I'd like to create an `Application` column and hopefully fill this with the name of the child application the error occurred in.

How can I accomplish this? Is there a way to pull the module that the error occured in, or similar? That way I can wrap my `ErrorLoggerService` conditionals in a larger if statement which reads something like:

```
if (error is from Application A) {
    var appName = Application A; 
    //log errors to db
} else if (error is from Application B) {
    var appName = Application A:
    //log errors to db
}
```